# Setup Angular 4 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio

I would like to develop Angular web application using Visual Studio 2017.
I have created a new project choosing Asp.net Web application with Empty template.

Now I am little bit confused about the files that needs to be copied/included to the project from the attached screenshot.

Can someone help me to identify the required files and their purpose.

[image]

Comment: `node_modules` and `package-lock` is something which is generated on doing `npm install` so you can ignore them.

Comment: @vishu minhas - I thought, visual studio 2017 has more features than code. I am not sure whether I should use code or 2017 IDE since I am a .net developer and new to Angular.

Comment: See this if you want to make things a little easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular CLI to generate the files required to create an angular project, using 
command:

```
ng new NameOfProject
```

I prefer to use VS code editor to control over angular script and use VS IDE to interact with server side.

you can put all angular files in the root of your project. 
[image]

Comment: @Dipak Delvadiya - Can you plz help me to understand below line.
'I prefer to use VS code editor to control over angular script and use VS IDE to interact with server side'.  Do we need to use separate IDE for Client side and Server side code.  i.e for Client side - VS Code and for Server side - VS 2017.

Comment: if you want to handle your code better (personal preference) you can handle angular scripting (client side) using vs code to generate components, services, etc...  using vs code will give you the ability to speed up coding when using extensions such as auto import also you can use integrated terminal to build angular scripts on the other hand you can use vs2017 to handle server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is the workspace of your project : you'll find more information about the structure [here](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure)

Answer (score 1):

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

npm install -g npm

npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm run start:stage

or

npm run start:localapi